# trying to insert data(s) in my table user_objective and is not able to do so.No value goes in table created.Label returns"0 value inserted"

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010

```
 protected void LinkButtonContacts_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string obj1 = TextBox6.Text.Trim();
        string obj2 = TextBox7.Text.Trim();
        string obj3 = TextBox8.Text.Trim();
        string queryUpdate = "Update User_Objectives SET Objective1= @Objective1 , Objective2=@Objective2 ,Objective3=@Objective3 WHERE Email='useremail'";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=resume;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryUpdate, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Objective1", TextBox6.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Objective2", TextBox7.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Objective3",TextBox8.Text );
        int added = 0;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            added = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Label1.Text = added + "record inserted";
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            Label1.Text = "error inserting record";
            Label1.Text = Label1.Text + err.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Did you debug your code line by line? Your code looks fine to me..

Comment: If you are trying to `insert` then why your query is `update` ?

Comment: Does your query make any changes in the database?

Comment: Please provide some context (what you are trying to accomplish, what specifically is going wrong) so we can more adequately debug your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things in your code:

- First you are trying to `Update` a record, not `INSERT`.
- 2nd You are updating the record based on `useremail` passed in the
  where clause. Your variable `added` should have the count of rows
  effected, but your query is not finding any record to update based on
  the search parameter.

Currently in your where clause you have `WHERE Email='useremail'`. You are passing a string literal, instead pass the email address you expect to be updated in the table. You can use extra SqlParameter for that as well like you are doing with your rest of the parameters.